# Residual variance of a variable in Structured Equation Modeling

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I am following lavaan package in R to implement SEM. I have a doubt for residual correlation equation.

http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/sem.html

in general, in residual correlations equations,   y1 ~~ y5 represent correlation between y1 and y5 which is not explained by their latent variables but what is the meaning of y1 ~~ y1 ?

1)  I am not able to relate it with residual correlation of same variable as how the errors are calculated for residuals?

2) Is there some kind of regression fitting of y1 with y1 ( doesn't make sense)?

Comment: Using the ~~ operator with the same variables on either side is how you manually specify the estimation of a variance. See the lavaan website for details: http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/syntax1.html

Answer (score 1):

y1 ~~ y1 is the covariance (not correlation) of a variable with itself.

The covariance of a variable with itself is the variance.

Compare the formula for the variance and covariance:

$cov(x, y) = \frac{(x-\bar{x})(y-\bar{y})}{N-1} $

$var(x) = \frac{(x-\bar{x})(x-\bar{x})}{N-1} $

Comment: i understood but what does it mean ? What is the significance of having high or low variance of a variable in SEM? Does it contain any information other than 'values are changing/fluctuating a lot' ?

Comment: It's a latent variable - it's unexplained variance. Just like the residual variance in a regression.